# seeing php statement twice, how can I fix that?

Tags: php

I have a issue with php. To view a profile on my site, you have to be user/member. Well, that works, but if you click on the link of the profile as a guest,  you can't see a thing. That ain't a problem, but I want to fill it up with something or redirect guests to the register page. If I change the `a href`, that has to work, I know. But the main problem is that the `UPDATEDATE` statement, which shows a message's edited date (if it is edited of course). As a member, you can see it just where it belongs: after the person's nick, but if you are a guest, you see it double/twice! You see it in the right way, after a person's nick, but you also see the updated date on the message itself and that isn't right. How can I fix this date problem?

I have tried the following code:

```
if ($verified_user)
       echo "
          <div align=right class=aul>
            $tag $spit $move $remove

           (<a href=\"home.php?process=who=$nick\" title=\"$usertitle\" style=\"text-decoration: none;\">$user</a></span>, ".dateTime($date2);

if($updatedate!=""){echo " ~ $updatedate";} 

        echo ")";
```

and for guests:

```
if (!$verified_user)
  echo "
          <div align=right class=aul>
             $tag $spit $move $remove

           (<a href=\"home.php?process=who=$nick\" title=\"$usertitle\" style=\"text-decoration: none;\">$user</a></span>, ".dateTime($date2);

if($updatedate!=""){echo " ~ $updatedate";} 

    echo ")";
```

Comment: It seems you have forgotten the braces around the blocks of your `if ($verified_user)`/`if (!$verified_user)` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the **{** for the if:

```
if ($verified_user) {
  echo "
    <div align=right class=aul> $tag $spit $move $remove    
      (<a href=\"home.php?process=who=$nick\" title=\"$usertitle\" 
       style=\"text-  decoration: none;\">$user</a></span>, ".dateTime($date2);

   if($updatedate!="") {echo " ~ $updatedate";}     
   echo ")";

}
```

Comment: I thank you, lanzz and JvdBerg, for your quick and RIGHT answers. It works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

you need to add more curly brackets in you IFs - include `if($updatedate!='')...` into the brackets of `if (!$verified_user) { ... if($updatedate!='') {...}  }`

or do the following (i think it is better):

```
if (!$verified_user) {
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
if($updatedate!='') { ... }
```